# Untar failed due to compressed data--format error?

Tags: command-line, server, 20.04, tar

I've been trying to untar this file for several days now, and every time I try it again it ends up corrupting the file and creating corrupted files and directories. I have tried reinstalling tar and still get errors, and am not sure why it isn't working. I'm pretty certain that it downloaded correctly, and know that others have gotten the same file to untar. Any ideas on why this isn't working or what I could do to fix it?

```
$ tar xfvz ftm_opera_pruned_21-12-17_06-01-01.tar.gz

tar: \324co\320\346$\363\n\344{ę0@e\034\002\a\004%)F{9JS\275\306\023?\313\373\302\342ؕ\343D\212\t\306\026\361\034qYT`>#\001\362\:\266Y\026*\t\360\232\003Y\016\240: Cannot hard link to ‘\316\375\372\277Y\217d\241\356\367\221\252x\023\030\277\027\202\355\200\002\004%)x#\211\0306]\352r\354\201\031\316\305%Ɛ\331/d#\377B\227pj\330\374\216,\001a\177m`\t\241\034\004\242̠’: No such file or directory
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Archive contains ‘\216\020D\312ca\370T\357\006\001{’ where numeric off_t value expected
tar: Archive contains ‘?\251\332K\355\307rǃ\005\251\302’ where numeric off_t value expected
tar: Archive contains ‘\326%`\0\021i\0x\r5\262\351’ where numeric off_t value expected
tar: Archive contains ‘\352\214K\177\355\357H\217ё+\325’ where numeric off_t value expected
tar: Archive contains ‘V\033\3138\261\2161q\275\350\t$’ where numeric off_t value expected
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: Also please run `file ftm_opera_pruned_21-12-17_06-01-01.tar.gz` and share the output.

Comment: ftm_opera_pruned_21-12-17_06-01-01.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 1108811776

Comment: does `tar -xf ftm_opera_pruned...tar.gz` give you the same output?

Comment: Yes it seems to be doing the same exact thing.